# Anyone know what the symbols on the right of the wp7 in debug are all about?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

Thias is a screenshot of the right hand side of the application in the emulator, these also appear when I deploy to the phone device. what are they, are they supposed to be there?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values are stats like frame rate count, and info about cpu and memory usage.

You often keep them on during debugging but turn them off for release.

This is best done in the constructor of the App clas e.g.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Constructor for the Application object.
    /// </summary>
    public App()
    {
        // Global handler for uncaught exceptions. 
        UnhandledException += Application_UnhandledException;

        // Phone-specific initialization
        InitializePhoneApplication();

        // Standard Silverlight initialization
        InitializeComponent();

        // XNA initialization
        InitializeXnaApplication();

        DispatcherHelper.Initialize();

        // Show graphics profiling information while debugging.
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            // Display the current frame rate counters.
            Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;

            // Show the areas of the app that are being redrawn in each frame.
            //Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableRedrawRegions = true;

            // Enable non-production analysis visualization mode, 
            // which shows areas of a page that are handed off to GPU with a colored overlay.
            //Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableCacheVisualization = true;

            // Disable the application idle detection by setting the UserIdleDetectionMode property of the
            // application's PhoneApplicationService object to Disabled.
            // Caution:- Use this under debug mode only. Applications that disable user idle detection will continue to run
            // and consume battery power when the user is not using the phone.
            PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
        }

        //set up the tile
        //StartSearchAgent();
        //ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest("shottracker", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }
```

So you set the EnableFrameRateCounter to false etc.

Detailed info about the values can be found here

[Frame Rate Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg588380%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)